# Declare a type from a JSON nested objects dynamically in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a JSON file that looks like that:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "key1_1": "value1_1",
    "key1_2": "value1_2",
    ...
    "key1_n": "value1_n"
  },
  "key2": {
    "key2_1": "value2_1",
    "key2_2": "value2_2",
    ...
    "key2_m": "value2_m"
  },
  ...
  "keyx": {
    "keyx_1": "valuex_1",
    "keyx_2": "valuex_2",
    ...
    "keyx_y": "valuex_y",
  }
}
```

I'm trying to declare a type for the nested objects of each `keyx`. I tried:

```
import data from './data.json';

type Data = typeof data;
type Key = keyof Data;
type Nested = Data[Key];
```

The goal is to have a custom hook in React that get a key and returns the nested object of that key:

```
const d = useData('key1');
d.key1_1 // call it
```

The json object can be dynamic but only in this structure, no more than one level of nesting.

How can I define this type properly so that I can call it as:

```
data.keyx.keyx_y
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need a type? You can already access the properties `.key1.key1_1` from `data`.

Comment: @TobiasS. i'm implementing a custom hook in react with some logic that at the end result with on of the nested object. so you can use `const d = useData('key1')` and `d` will be `{key1_1: val1_1, etc..`.

Comment: Why not include this in the question then? It is not really clear how your current question relates to the problem of the comment.

Comment: "Dynamic" and [tag:typescript] don't really go together. All you can say about the data structure then is that it's an object with string keys and objects as values (which have string keys and values). This needs to be known *statically*, since the types are only checked statically.

Comment: Is the following type meeting your criteria? @user12499410 https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgczsKBeKAGKAfKBGHKAJkIGZCAWQgVkIDZCB2QgDkIE4AoT0SKAOQCuAWwBGEAE4BnNFAAGAEgDe8JMAC+cwoqUBRAB4BjADaCAJhAA8q5ABpMAPnXKbGrbh0GT5q6-sYnF0RkZxVgt25eaABJADsAM0khMUkAMQkAe2EAaQgQS2yHWWyoCH1gCFizGTkAazzlOATJAU0oAH4BKAAuKFiIADdJSPBoGABDYHHZJShOKAWoAG0Spvl6kGVk8WlNAF1epXnFk6WABSg1uoalOMSJbbTMnLyCpwB9LZEdqX3eqWAEiaCGOC3UnHB3E4FhM4wk0EMGViAKgZkm416Eym3DRUwAdBtSAS8qR3ngMKQgA

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta nice but the `key..` is just an example it can be any word..

Comment: @user12499410 it isn't clear from the original question